# How to avoid the exception "Transceive failed" when reading data from NFC tag type A?

Tags: android, nfc

I'm working on an app that should be able to emulate the copy NFC-tags of any type. After reading the data from the zero blocks and page marks type "NFC type A" and "MIFARE Ultralight" (label types in my possession yet) using the methods:

```
nfcA.transceive()
```

and

```
mifareUltralight.readPages()
```

The rest of the data can not be read, but throws an exception "Transceive failed".

Here is the code for the appropriate methods. For NfcA:

```
private static ArrayList<IdNameValue> readeNfcADataset(final Tag tag, final Context cxt) {

    String excMsg = "";
    ArrayList<IdNameValue> dataSet = new ArrayList<>();
    NfcA nfcA = NfcA.get(tag);

    if (nfcA != null) {

        dataSet.add(new IdNameValue(cxt.getString(R.string.atqa) + " ",
                "0x" + byteArrayToHexString(nfcA.getAtqa())));
        dataSet.add(new IdNameValue(cxt.getString(R.string.sak) + " ",
                "0x" + shortToHexString(nfcA.getSak())));

        byte blockNumber = 0x00;
        int bytesNumber = 1, pagesNumber = 16, counter = 0;
        byte[][] bytes = new byte[pagesNumber][bytesNumber];

        excMsg = "_________________________________________________\n" +
                cxt.getString(R.string.picc_compliant_with_iso_iec_14443_3A_fnca) + ":";
        Log.i(TAG, excMsg);

        for (int i = 0; i < pagesNumber; i++) {

            excMsg = "";
            while (!nfcA.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    nfcA.connect();
                    excMsg = cxt.getString(R.string.connecting_to_tag_has_been_created);
                    Log.i(TAG, 109 + ": " + excMsg);

                    bytes[i] = nfcA.transceive(new byte[]{
                            (byte) 0x30,  // READ
                            (byte) (blockNumber & 0x0FF)
                    });
                    excMsg = cxt.getString(R.string.made_to_read_data_from_a_block)
                            + Integer.toHexString(blockNumber);
                    Log.i(TAG, 117 + ": " + excMsg);
                    if (nfcA.isConnected()) nfcA.close();
                    excMsg += cxt.getString(R.string.tag_has_been_closed);
                    break;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    counter++;
                    excMsg = e.getMessage() + ":> " + (excMsg.equals("") ?
                            cxt.getString(R.string.the_connection_tag_is_not_created) :
                            (excMsg.contains(cxt.getString(R.string.connecting_to_tag_has_been_created)) ||
                                    excMsg.contains(cxt.getString(R.string.made_to_read_data_from_a_page))) ?
                                    "Failed to read data from a tag block: "
                                            + Integer.toHexString(blockNumber) :
                                    cxt.getString(R.string.error_closing_tag));
                    Log.e(TAG, 130 + ": " + excMsg);
                }

                if (nfcA.isConnected()) try {
                    nfcA.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    excMsg += (":> " + e1.getMessage());
                    Log.e(TAG, 137 + ": " + excMsg);
                }

                if (counter > 9) {
                    excMsg = cxt.getString(R.string.the_number_of_connection_attempts_exceeded_the_number_of_ten);

                    Log.e(TAG, 143 + ": " + excMsg);
                    break;
                }
            }
            counter = 0;
            blockNumber += (byte) bytes[i].length;
        }

        if (excMsg.equals(cxt.getString(R.string.the_number_of_connection_attempts_has_exceeded_one_hundred))) {
            dataSet.add(new IdNameValue("Error", " reading the data tag"));
            return dataSet;
        }

        dataSet.add(new IdNameValue("Page", "    0    1    2    3"));

        String name = "";
        String value = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < pagesNumber; i++) {
            if (!value.equals("")) dataSet.add(new IdNameValue(name, value));
            name = (i > 9 ? " " : "    ") + String.valueOf(i) + "   ";
            value = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < bytes[i].length; j++) {
                value += ("  " + byteToHexString(bytes[i][j]));
            }
        }
        dataSet.add(new IdNameValue(name, value));
        return dataSet;
    }
    return dataSet;
}
```

For MifareUltraligh:

```
private static ArrayList<IdNameValue> readeMifareUltralightDataset(final Tag tag, final Context cxt) {

    MifareUltralight mifareUltralight = MifareUltralight.get(tag);
    String excMsg = "";
    int bytesNumber = 1, pagesNumber = 4, counter = 0, startBlock;
    byte[][] bytes = new byte[pagesNumber][bytesNumber];
    startBlock = 0x00;

    excMsg = "_________________________________________________\n" +
            cxt.getString(R.string.mifare_ultralight_or_ultralight_c) + ":";
    Log.i(TAG, excMsg);

    for (int i = 0; i < pagesNumber; i++) {

        while (!mifareUltralight.isConnected()) {
            excMsg = "";
            try {
                mifareUltralight.connect();
                excMsg = cxt.getString(R.string.connecting_to_tag_has_been_created);
                Log.i(TAG, 201 + ": " + excMsg);

                bytes[i] = mifareUltralight.readPages(startBlock);
                excMsg = cxt.getString(R.string.done_reading_pages_twice_blocks)
                        + Integer.toHexString(startBlock) + " - "
                        + Integer.toHexString((startBlock + bytes[i].length) - 1);
                Log.i(TAG, 207 + ": " + excMsg);
                if (mifareUltralight.isConnected()) mifareUltralight.close();
                excMsg = cxt.getString(R.string.tag_has_been_closed);
                Log.i(TAG, 210 + ": " + excMsg);
                break;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                counter++;
                excMsg = e.getMessage() + ":> " + (excMsg.equals("") ?
                        cxt.getString(R.string.the_connection_tag_is_not_created) :
                        (excMsg.contains(cxt.getString(R.string.connecting_to_tag_has_been_created)) ||
                                excMsg.contains(cxt.getString(R.string.done_reading_pages_twice_blocks)) ?
                                "Failed to read page from tag blocks: "
                                        + Integer.toHexString(startBlock) + " - "
                                        + Integer.toHexString(startBlock + bytes[i].length - 1) :
                                cxt.getString(R.string.error_closing_tag)));
                Log.e(TAG, 222 + ": " + excMsg);
            }

            if (mifareUltralight.isConnected()) try {
                mifareUltralight.close();
                break;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                excMsg = (":> " + e.getMessage());
                Log.e(TAG, 230 + ": " + excMsg);
            }

            if (counter > 9) {
                excMsg = cxt.getString(R.string.the_number_of_connection_attempts_exceeded_the_number_of_ten);
                Log.e(TAG, 236 + ": " + excMsg);
                break;
            }
        }
        counter = 0;
        startBlock += bytes[i].length;
    }

    ArrayList<IdNameValue> dataSet = new ArrayList<>();
    if (excMsg.equals(cxt.getString(R.string.the_number_of_connection_attempts_has_exceeded_one_hundred))) {
        dataSet.add(new IdNameValue("Error", " reading the data tag"));
        return dataSet;
    }

    dataSet.add(new IdNameValue("Page", "    0    1    2    3"));

    int n = -1;
    String name = "";
    String value = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < pagesNumber; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < bytes[i].length; j++) {
            if (j % 4 == 0) {
                n++;
                if (!value.equals("")) dataSet.add(new IdNameValue(name, value));
                name = (n > 9 ? " " : "    ") + String.valueOf(n) + "   ";
                value = "";
            }
            value += ("  " + byteToHexString(bytes[i][j]));
        }
    }
    dataSet.add(new IdNameValue(name, value));
    return dataSet;
}
```

It fragments the resulting log:

```
...cardreader I/TagController: _________________________________________________
                               PICC compliant with ISO/IEC 14443-3A (NFCA):
...cardreader I/TagController: 109: The connecting to tag has been created
...cardreader I/TagController: 117: Made to read data from a block: 0
...cardreader I/TagController: 109: The connecting to tag has been created
...cardreader E/TagController: 130: Transceive failed:> Failed to read data from a tag block: 10
...cardreader I/TagController: 109: The connecting to tag has been created
...cardreader E/TagController: 130: Transceive failed:> Failed to read data from a tag block: 10
...........................................................
...cardreader I/TagController: 109: The connecting to tag has been created
...cardreader E/TagController: 130: Transceive failed:> Failed to read data from a tag block: 1e
...cardreader E/TagController: 143: The number of connection attempts exceeded the number of ten.
...cardreader I/TagController: _________________________________________________
                               MIFARE Ultralight or Ultralight C:
...cardreader I/TagController: 201: The connecting to tag has been created
...cardreader I/TagController: 207: Done reading pages twice blocks:0 - f
...cardreader I/TagController: 210: Tag has been closed
...cardreader I/TagController: 201: The connecting to tag has been created
...cardreader E/TagController: 222: Transceive failed:> Failed to read page from tag blocks: 10 - 10
...cardreader I/TagController: 201: The connecting to tag has been created
...cardreader E/TagController: 222: Transceive failed:> Failed to read page from tag blocks: 11 - 11
...cardreader I/TagController: 201: The connecting to tag has been created
...cardreader E/TagController: 222: Transceive failed:> Failed to read page from tag blocks: 12 - 12
```

The fact that the data in the remaining blocks are available shows the output port monitor program "Arduino 1.8.5":

```
Card UID: 04 3A 31 02 54 2E 82
Card SAK: 00
PICC type: MIFARE Ultralight or Ultralight C
Page  0  1  2  3
  0   04 3A 31 87
  1   02 54 2E 82
  2   FA 48 F0 00
  3   FF FF FF FC
  4   45 D9 B0 49
  5   9E 6A 2D 00
  6   1E 82 00 00
  7   1E 82 00 00
  8   1E 7E 05 00
  9   40 00 08 09
 10   B7 DD DB FF
 11   1E 7E 98 48
 12   1E 7E 05 00
 13   40 00 08 09
 14   B7 DD DB FF
 15   1E 7E 98 48
```

In the screenshot below, the application demonstrates that the label allows to read the data on the type, technologies and UID:
  [The output data read from the label on its type, technology, and UID](https://yadi.sk/i/jzeR1_EK3Pgg2k)

Below shows the output read from the tag, the first 16 byts of data.
For NFC type A:
  [The output read from the data labels (for NFC type A)](https://yadi.sk/i/Zt13CRfG3PggMn)

For MIFARE Ultralight:
  [The output read from the data labels (for MIFARE Ultralight)](https://yadi.sk/i/mcyjEZpB3Pggaq)
As can be seen, the system reads ONLY the FIRST 16 byts. What could be wrong? Please any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long looking through the documentation, namely ["MF0ICU1 MIFARE Ultralight contactless single-ticket IC" / Rev. 3.9 — 23 July 2014 #028639](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MF0ICU1.pdf) and ["MF0ICU2 MIFARE Ultralight C" / Rev. 3.2 — 19 May 2009 #171432](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MF0ICU2_SDS.pdf) led, eventually and understanding of the problem: all the salt in the block addressing which is supplied to the command input READE. The calculation of the number block for type tag NFCA should look like this:

```
blockNumber = (byte) (i * 4);
```

and for the label type Mifare Ultralight:

```
startBlock = i * 4;
```

Then everything takes off.